# Confusion about finding eigenvectors from matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

I'm doing the following question here:

> Find the determinant of $A$=\begin{bmatrix} 
>    6 & 2 & 2 & 2 &2 \\ 
>    2 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 
>    2 & 2 & 6 & 2 & 2 \\ 
>    2 & 2 & 2 & 6 & 2 \\ 
>    2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 6 
>    \end{bmatrix}.

The solution is given [here](https://yutsumura.com/determinant-of-matrix-whose-diagonal-entries-are-6-and-2-elsewhere/).

I understand all of this. The only part I am not sure about is why the solution seems to seemingly go $$B\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 \\ 
    1 \\ 
     1 \\ 
    1 \\ 
    1 
    \end{bmatrix}=10\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 \\ 
    1 \\ 
     1 \\ 
    1 \\ 
    1 
    \end{bmatrix}.$$

Where did that vector come from? It seems extremely random and I am not sure what the reasoning was for that choice.

I understand $0$ is an eigenvalue for $B$ since the matrix is not invertible (Since we have two rows that are exactly the same and hence the determinant is $0$.)

The algebraic multiplicity for $0$ is $4$ since $10$ is also an eigenvalue and hence, since $1\leq \text{Geometric multiplicity} \leq \text{Algebraic multiplicity}$ we have that the algebraic multiplicity is $4$ and not $5$ as a consequence of $10$ also being an eigenvalue.

I get all this. However, I am not sure where the Eigenvalue of $10$ is coming from because of what I mentioned above. Can someone explain this? Thanks!

Comment: Hints: since every row is made up of the same vector, $B\vec{x}$ will always produce a vector that has the same number at every position, since each entry is just the dot product of row in $B$ and $\vec{x}$.

Comment: notice that you can write $B = 2vv^T$ where $v$ is that vector

Answer (score 1):

Note that the matrix is very "symmetric" not only in the linear algebra sense of the term :

If you look directly to $A$, you can notice that called $e$ the vector of all $1$'s, we have that $A e = A e_1 + A e_2+\cdots A e_6$; but in generale given $e_i$ the $i$-th vector of the standard basis $Ae_i = A^i$, the $i-$th column of the matrix.

In this case taking $Ae$ corresponds to summing all the column of the matrix, which by "symmetry" corresponds to $14$ the vector $e$, since summing each line corresponds to have a $14$ factor in each entry.

This is a useful standard trick to spot eigenvector (i.e summing columns in appropriate way which corresponds to find non trivial linear combinations) and from here simply note that $B = A-4I$ in this way $B e = Ae - 4e = 10 e$.